# Where in Bundle set InstallPrivileges = "elevated". Bootstrapper Wix

Tags: wix, bundle, bootstrapper

I find to set administration privilages for Wix installer you have to set:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>
```

in `<Product/>`. But where/how set that for Bundle, because I cant create `<Package/>` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper13" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="" UpgradeCode="86064926-b150-448f-aba9-fb0c8f4a83b5">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn automatically detects when you have a `perMachine` package; you don't have to tell it.

Comment: I want to conf iis in custon action which need administration privilage. But probably i should do that in WIX